# How to use date range Query in Mongo Mock python

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I am trying to use Mongo mock with date Range Query in python

I had tried using `$date ({ "$date" : "2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"})` in the Query but I can't get the Response

Then I used `datetime.datetime()`

Using that I got Exception in Mockmongo

```
Error : can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode
```

Can you please tell me how to use date range Query in MockMongo?